# Oracle Application Framework, Flexfield References, view of Segment List

Tags: oracle, oaf

I have the problem with oracle OAF. At screen you see "about page".
4 field in red square: level_2016, branch_2016, group_2016, speciality_2016 - not visible in green square "Segment list".

[About Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciAlF.png)

1) This fields used in region. In personalization there is no field for tining "Segment list". See pictures:

[Personalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHFzv.png)
[Personalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vhtr.png)

2) In controller where is same code (I don't see hide fields).

```js
package oracle.apps.irc.candidateSelfService.webui;

import java.io.Serializable;
import oracle.apps.fnd.common.VersionInfo;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAApplicationModule;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAViewObject;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.OAPageContext;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.OADescriptiveFlexBean;
import oracle.apps.fnd.framework.webui.beans.OAWebBean;
import oracle.apps.irc.common.webui.IrcOAControllerImpl;

public class IrcCandidateEduDetailsCO extends IrcOAControllerImpl
{
  public static final String RCS_ID = "$Header: IrcCandidateEduDetailsCO.java 120.3 2005/09/30 07:10:40 mmillmor noship $";
  public static final boolean RCS_ID_RECORDED = VersionInfo.recordClassVersion("$Header: IrcCandidateEduDetailsCO.java 120.3 2005/09/30 07:10:40 mmillmor noship $", "oracle.apps.irc.candidateSelfService.webui");

  public void processRequest(OAPageContext paramOAPageContext, OAWebBean paramOAWebBean)
  {
    super.processRequest(paramOAPageContext, paramOAWebBean);

    OADescriptiveFlexBean localOADescriptiveFlexBean1 = (OADescriptiveFlexBean)paramOAWebBean.findIndexedChildRecursive("IrcFlexField3");

    if ((localOADescriptiveFlexBean1 != null) && (localOADescriptiveFlexBean1.isRendered())) {
      localOADescriptiveFlexBean1.setFlexPrefix("Pea");
    }
    OADescriptiveFlexBean localOADescriptiveFlexBean2 = (OADescriptiveFlexBean)paramOAWebBean.findIndexedChildRecursive("QualFlexField");

    if ((localOADescriptiveFlexBean2 != null) && (localOADescriptiveFlexBean2.isRendered())) {
      localOADescriptiveFlexBean2.setFlexPrefix("Pqs");
    }

    OAViewObject localOAViewObject = (OAViewObject)paramOAPageContext.getApplicationModule(paramOAWebBean).findViewObject("IrcCandidateEduVO");
    if (localOAViewObject != null)
      localOAViewObject.invokeMethod("runQuery");
  }

  public void processFormRequest(OAPageContext paramOAPageContext, OAWebBean paramOAWebBean)
  {
    super.processFormRequest(paramOAPageContext, paramOAWebBean);

    String str1 = getIrcAction(paramOAPageContext);
    String str2;
    if ("DELETEEDU".equals(str1))
    {
      str2 = getIrcActionValue(paramOAPageContext);
      paramOAPageContext.getRootApplicationModule().invokeMethod("deleteEdu", new Serializable[] { str2 });
      super.refreshImmediately(paramOAPageContext);
    } else if ("AddEduQual".equals(str1))
    {
      str2 = getIrcActionValue(paramOAPageContext);
      paramOAPageContext.getRootApplicationModule().invokeMethod("addEduQual", new Serializable[] { str2 });
      super.refreshImmediately(paramOAPageContext);
    } else if ("DeleteEduQual".equals(str1))
    {
      str2 = paramOAPageContext.getParameter("IrcAttVal");
      String str3 = paramOAPageContext.getParameter("IrcQulVal");
      paramOAPageContext.getRootApplicationModule().invokeMethod("deleteEduQual", new Serializable[] { str2, str3 });

      super.refreshImmediately(paramOAPageContext);
    }
  }

  public boolean isAMStateSet(OAPageContext paramOAPageContext)
  {
    String str1 = getIrcAction(paramOAPageContext);
    if ("EduQuals".equals(str1))
    {
      String str2 = getIrcActionValue(paramOAPageContext);
      paramOAPageContext.getRootApplicationModule().invokeMethod("showEduQualInfo", new Serializable[] { str2 });
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

So, how can I view this 4 fiels?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. It is necessary to export the region through the authority of the "Function Administrator". It rigidly spelled out the fields that you want to display. Let's edit the list of fields as we need. Then upload our personalization of the region.